# A question regarding Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Note: $\psi,\psi^{\dagger} :\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ and $x, \lambda_i , \hbar, m \in \Bbb{R}$

Say we know that $\lambda_1$ is a solution to the eigenvalue equation: $$\hat{\Pi}\psi(x)= \lambda_1 \psi(x) .$$ Now for the complex conjugate of $\psi$, to be denoted as $\psi^{\dagger}$, is the eigenfunction for the eigenvalue problem
$$\hat{\Pi}\psi^{\dagger}(x)=\lambda_2\psi^{\dagger}(x)$$  the same as the first, or its negative, or totally different? In other words, is
$$\lambda_1=\lambda_2 \text{ ?}$$

Thank you!

This is in reference to a quantum mechanics problem, in which I try to prove the following:
Given  $$j(x,t)=\frac{\hbar}{2 i m} \left[ \psi(x)^{\dagger}\frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x}-\psi(x)\frac{\partial \psi(x)^{\dagger}}{\partial x } \right]$$
Show it can be represented in the form 
$$j(x,t) =\operatorname{Re} \left[ \psi(x)^{\dagger}\frac{\hbar}{i m}\frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x} \right]$$

This is related because the momentum operator is defined as  $\hat{P}= -i \hbar \hat{\nabla}=-i \hbar \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$  in one dimension, and this can be substituted into the Eigenvalues problem and simplified.

Comment: Does $x \in \Bbb{C}?$ And $\psi (x)$ is a function $\Bbb{C}\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$?

Comment: Added answer to your comment to question.

Comment: I am not familiar with Quantum Mechanics I fear, but it is known that eigenvalues of real matrices do come in conjugate pairs. That is,  if $A$ is a square matrix with entries real numbers and $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $λ$, then $\bar x$ is an eigenvector of A for the eigenvalue $\bar λ $. The problem lies in the value $\hat{\Pi}\psi(x)= \lambda_1 \psi(x)$ as far as I can tell. If $Π$ corresponds to a matrix with real values I think you have your answer.

Comment: Since $\lambda_i \in \Bbb{R}$, $\text{Im}[\lambda_i]=0 \implies \lambda_1=\lambda_1^{\dagger}=\lambda_2$?

Comment: Does $\hat{\Pi}\psi(x)= \lambda_1 \psi(x)$ represent a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$? If so, I believe your assertion is correct and $λ_1= \bar λ_1= λ_2$.

Comment: It's a linear operator. I am not sure if that means it's a transformation. But, i know psi is usually complex but lambda must be real, as it is an observable quantity. So I think so?

Comment: very often (almost always in the usual quantum mechanics), operators are Hermitian. Meaning that the eigenvalues have to be real, so the condition you mentioned is fulfilled. Another way for solving your problem is to demonstrate that the momentum operator is Hermitian (sure you are able to find demonstrations of this fact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need for your problem is the following: if $z$ is a complex number, then 
$$
\frac{z + z^\dagger}{2} = \text{Re}(z), \qquad \frac{z - z^\dagger}{2i} = \text{Im}(z), \qquad \text{Im}(z) = \text{Re}(\tfrac{z}{i}).
$$
See if you can prove these by writing $z = a + bi$, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$, and performing the indicated operators.

Turning to your equation for probability current, we can set $z = \psi^\dagger(x)\tfrac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x}$, so $z^\dagger = \psi(x) \tfrac{\partial \psi^\dagger(x)}{\partial x}$. Then
$$
j(x,t) = \frac{\hbar}{2 i m} (z - z^\dagger) = \frac{\hbar}{m} \cdot \frac{z - z^\dagger}{2i} = \frac{\hbar}{m} \text{Im}(z) = \frac{\hbar}{m} \text{Re}\left(\frac{z}{i}\right) = \text{Re}\left( \frac{\hbar}{mi} z \right) = \text{Re}\left( \frac{\hbar}{mi} \psi^\dagger(x) \frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x} \right) 
$$
as desired.

Comment: I was hoping to solve it myself, but that answers my question as well. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the spoiler :(

Comment: It's alright. Saved me 20 minutes of work, though now I'll feel like I cheated. And I can't remove it from my head.

Comment: But still. Thank you so much!

Comment: Could u see why I was asking about operators though? It seemed to me the easiest attack plan was to sub in the momentum operator P and then lambda it's Eigenvalue, rearrange to get the sum of the two, than expand back out to P and back out to the original definition. But this requires the conjugate Eigenvalue is -1*eigenvalue. Would that have worked?

Comment: We could rewrite the final answer as $\text{Re}\left( \tfrac{1}{m} \psi^\dagger \hat{P} \psi \right)$. However, for eigenvalues of the momentum operator to be involved, we'd need to know that $\psi$ is a momentum eigenfunction, which may not be the case.

Comment: I believe it has to be by definition of the operator, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: In your probability current problem, $\psi$ can be *any* wavefunction. It doesn't have to be a wavefunction which is an eigenfunction of the momentum operator. And if it's not a momentum eigenfunction, we cannot write $\hat{P} \psi = \lambda \psi$.

Comment: That makes sense. Ty.